# How is SHA-256 hash size calculated?

Tags: hash, sha

SHA-256 gives us a 256-bit hash value for a given input. When I tried, I got the below hash for a random input string:

```
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
```

This hash has 64 characters. Considering common encodings, its size would be:

UTF-8 = 64 * 8 = 512 bits

UTF-16 = 64 * 16 = 1024 bits

So how come it's called a 256-bit hash? Am I doing an incorrect conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string **2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824** is a hex-encoded String. It's the bytes represented in base 16 numbers, so every 2 characters represent a single byte.

So **2c** is the first byte, **f2** is the second byte and so on. As the string has 64 characters, it represents 32 bytes.

And 32 bytes = 256 bits

Answer (score 3):

This is base16/hex representation, which only has 4 (log2 16) bits of data per byte.

Thus, sha256 is 4*64 here. Nothing is wrong.